# Can a pytest fixture know whether a test has passed or failed?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I'm writing some tests in pytest, and I'd like to make the fixture do something only if the test passes (update a value in a DB). It doesn't seem like fixtures in general know about whether the tests they run pass or fail -- is there a way to make them?

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(request):
    ...
    yield
    [if test passes]:
        db.write(new_value)


def test_foo(my_fixture):
    assert False
```

Trying to catch an exception doesn't work as pytest has its own exception handling which handles things before we'd hit my own:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(request):
    ...
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    else:
        db.write('new_value')
```

I've also tried inspecting the pytest `request` object, but it doesn't seem to have what I want

I suspect doing things this way doesn't follow the philosophy of pytest, so I'll probably end up doing things a different way in reality, but I'm interested to know the answer nonetheless :)

Comment: I guess you can do something hacky as manually `try`/`catch` inside the test itself and then `else: db.write('new_value')` if there is no exceptions, but this sounds more like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: i don't think this is an XY problem -- as in my final para, this is a question born of interest, not something i'm likely to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introspect the test context by requesting the `request` object in the fixture. There you can get `request.session.testsfailed`

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(request):
    failed_count = request.session.testsfailed
    yield
    if request.session.testsfailed > failed_count:
        print("this test failed")
```

Comment: Actually counting is sort of redundant, all that's needed is to check whether `request.session.testsfailed` evaluates to `True` for that test